# Have I properly used $\,\exists !\,$ in this statement?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

I want to express the following in logical notation.

> For every natural number, there is a unique natural number that succeeds it.

Does the following statement express that proposition?

$\forall n(n\in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (\exists !m(m\in\mathbb{N} \wedge m=n+1))$

Thank you,

-Hal

Comment: What is the universe over which your $\forall$ is quantifying?  Similarly, what about your $\exists$?

Comment: @Vadimi123 The $\forall$ and $\exists !$ quantify over the natural numbers. Would you have differently notated it?

Comment: If you quantify over the natural numbers, there's no need to write $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I see. $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}(\exists !m\in\mathbb{N}(m=n+1))$ $\Longleftrightarrow \forall n (n\in\mathbb{N}...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've done a good job expressing the proposition, using logical notation.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm: $\exists !n(...)$ expresses that the parenthetical portion of the statement characterizes one, and only one, $n$, but does not preclude other $n$ from existing?

Comment: It does not preclude other natural numbers from existing; it makes explicit that for every natural number $n$, there exists a unique successor $m$.

Answer (score 1):

> For every natural number, there is a unique natural number that succeeds it.

You could make use of the function notation. In set theoretic notation, we could have $S: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, or (my preference) $\forall x\in \mathbb{N}:S(x)\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $S(n)$ is the unique successor of $n$. The uniqueness of the successor is cleverly built into the notation.

Comment: A few questions about that: 1. The function $A\rightarrow B$ doesn't preclude two elements in $A$ from mapping to the same element in $B$. Is that correct? If so, then isn't true that $S:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{N}$ doesn't map the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ to unique successors in $\mathbb{N}$. How does that notation express the proposition in question?

Comment: 2. I'm not sure what $...S(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ means. In logical notation I would interpret that as 'for every $x$ included in the natural numbers, $x$ is a $S$ (where $S$ stands for the predicate 'is a unique successor of a natural number')that the natural numbers include'. If that's the correct interpretation, then it doesn't seem to explicitly express what a 'unique successor' entails. I suspect that I've misinterpreted your statement. Would you tell me how it works?

Comment: @Hal 1. Functions may be a many-to-one relation, just not one-to-many. So, $f: A\to B$ means that $f$ maps each element of $A$ to a *unique* element of $B$. 2. $S$ is not a logical predicate in this case. You might think of it as a set of ordered pairs, i.e. $y=S(x) \equiv (x,y)\in S$. If you have the usual rules of equality, this notation has functionality built into it.

Comment: Ah, I see. So $f$ maps each element of $A$ to a unique element of $B$ (i.e. to one element of $B$) but doesn't preclude other elements of $A$ from mapping to that same element in $B$. (e.g. $4\in A$ and $1\in A$ both may map to $9\in B$, but $4\in A$ may not map to $7\in  B$ and $6\in B$.) Accordingly, we would need another axiom that stipulates that no two natural numbers precede the same successor; correct?

Comment: @Hal Correct. That is, in fact, one of the Peano axioms. $S$ is injective. In set-theoretic notation: $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{N}:[S(x)=S(y)\implies x=y]$, or equivalently $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{N}:[x\ne y \implies S(x)\ne S(y)]$.